# Fastest way to sample sequences from a non-uniform distribution in numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, random

I want to generate a non-uniform random sample of a sequence of two elements, as made by numpy.choice()

e.g. I have the proportion p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0] of elements e=[0,1,2,3,4] (elements are here identified by there indices)
I want a sample of 3 sequences of two elements drawn from those proportions:
[03,23,32]

Here, we first drew 0 by sampling the element indexed zero which represents 10% of the total elements, we then drew 3 by sampling the element of index 3 which represents 60% of the elements : those two elements together result in a sequence '03'

Answer (score 0):

if you can find an integer N, that for every element `x` in `p`, that `x*N` is an integer, then you can:

```
p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0] 
N = 10

nums = []
for i, x in enumerate(p):
    nums.extend([i] * int(x*N))


import random
random.choice(nums)
```

If N is very large, then you can cumsum the proportion, and use `bisect` to search a random number between 0 and 1:

```
cp = []
s = 0
for x in p:
    s += x
    cp.append(s)

import bisect
[bisect.bisect_left(cp, random.random()) for i in range(10)]
```

If you use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

cp = np.cumsum(p)
np.searchsorted(cp, np.random.rand(10))
```

or:

```
np.random.choice(range(5), 10, p=p)
```